# Can changing order of two expansions change the result?

Tags: taylor-expansion, mathematica

I faced the problem : when expanding a function two times regarding to different variables, order of expansion is important! It seems really odd. How is it possible?

this is the function I wish to expand:

(r12 Cos[th] + G Sin[tp]) ((
   6 (z + G Cos[tp] + r12 Sin[th])^2 (2 z + G Cos[tp] + 
      r12 Sin[th]))/((2 z + G Cos[tp] + 
       r12 Sin[th])^2 + (r12 Cos[th] + G Sin[tp])^2)^(5/2) + (
   2 z + G Cos[tp] + 
    r12 Sin[th])/((2 z + G Cos[tp] + r12 Sin[th])^2 + (r12 Cos[th] + 
       G Sin[tp])^2)^(
   3/2) - ((z + G Cos[tp] + r12 Sin[th]) (5 (G^2 + r12^2) + 32 z^2 - 
        3 r12^2 Cos[2 th] + 32 r12 z Sin[th] + 
        16 G Cos[tp] (2 z + r12 Sin[th]) + 
        G (3 G Cos[2 tp] + 4 r12 Cos[th] Sin[tp])))/((2 z + 
        G Cos[tp] + r12 Sin[th])^2 + (r12 Cos[th] + G Sin[tp])^2)^(
    5/2) + (G Cos[tp] + 
    r12 Sin[th])/(G^2 + r12^2 + 2 G r12 Sin[th + tp])^(3/2))

Comment: please type the function here using mathjax

Comment: the function is very very large. it is more than 50 pages in mathematica. @TheIntegrator

Comment: could you link to a file containing the outputs?

Comment: What does "to expand a function" mean in this context?

Comment: I have checked the result. The subtraction is not zero. @Somos

Comment: I don't think it is a bug in MM. There should be a math concept here. I have even faced this problem for a very simplified function. please check my edited question in above link @Somos

Comment: How are you sure that, the problem originates from series? @Somos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments on the Mathematica question notes, the problem is with your expectations. Suppose you have an expression $\, 1/(x+y). \,$ If you expand it in series centered at infinity in both variables in different order you get two different results. For example, first expand with $x$ and then with $y$ gives
 $\, 1/(x+y) = 1/x + (-y + O(1/y)^3)/x^2 + O(1/x)^3 \,$ while reversing the order gives $\, 1/(x+y) = 1/y + (-x + O(1/x)^3)/y^2 + O(1/y)^3. \,$ Dropping the
 $\,O()\,$ terms gives two different rational expressions. This is due to expanding in series of inverse powers gives unexpected results. This situation also happen when expanding power series centered at finite points if there are poles of the function. For example, $\, x y/(x + y) = x - x^2/y + O(x^3) = y - y^2/x + O(y^3). \,$ Dropping the $\,O()\,$ terms again gives two different rational expressions. This is unexpected but correct.

Comment: What if I substitute x and y in your example with x=1/x0 and y=1/y0 and then expand your function about x0=0 and y0=0?

Comment: the function 1/(x+y) is a well behaved function in (x,y)=(infinity,infinity). One should be able to write Taylor expansion for a well behaved function

Comment: Okay, Tell us -- what do you want it to be? $1/(x+y) = ?"